# CakePHP save snapshot of data as XML/JSON

Tags: mysql, xml, database, cakephp

I have a CakePHP/MySQL app which stores **Job** data in a variety of tables.

The **Job** data is used to eventually generate **Reports**. However I need to implement a way of creating **Report** *Versions* so that if **Job** data is modified a new **Report** *version* is created. It must keep a copy of all versions created.

I thought I'd approach this by having a **Reports** table associated with the **Job** table that takes an XML snapshot of the Job data. Whenever a **Report** is generated it creates a new **Report** record with a unique ID and associated Job ID along with an XML 'snapshot' of the data at that point.

Is this a sensible approach? I'm reluctant to store the xml snapshot as a file as there will be several thousand reports generated and I would like to keep the data secure in the database.

Lastly, How would I best go about saving the XML to the DB? I'm using the [XML Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1474/serialize) to generate the XML of the data but having trouble saving this. I'm certain this is due to the size of the XML generated (The Job I'm testing with generates 600+ lines of XML and comes in at 41KiB when manually inserted into DB...).

Am I going about this totally the wrong way? It feels right, given that I need to store 'snapshots' of the data and can then use the [XML Parser](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1486/Xml-parsing)  in later processing. Would JSON be more practical (I'm not all too familier with how I could use JSON data or whether it would be as structured...)

If anyone could help me out on this, I would most grateful.

---

**UPDATE:** I've managed to get it to save the XML by having it generated in the save function and then adding it to a $data array thats saved. But it's still racking up storage. Any ideas on a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Re: [JSON vs XML](http://www.json.org/xml.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered alkemann's [Revision behavior](https://github.com/alkemann/CakePHP-Assets/blob/master/models/behaviors/revision.php)?

Sounds like it might do what you're looking for (without involving XML).

Comment: This looks like a much better option. Many Thanks indeed!